What is the fixed field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3)$ with 3-cycle group?
While doing an exercise I am asked to calculate the fixed field of
$$L:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3)$$
by the subgroup
$$\langle (a,b,c) \rangle := \langle (\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{5} \zeta_3^2)\rangle$$
of $\text{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$. The notation $(a,b,c)$ means the corresponding 3-cycle in the sense of the $S_3$ isomorphism, i.e. $(a,b,c)$ is the automorphism which maps
$$a \mapsto b, b \mapsto c, c \mapsto a$$
I had the following idea. I know that $\langle (a,b,c) \rangle$ has order three. By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory we thus know
$$3 = |\langle (a,b,c) \rangle| = [L:L^{\langle (a,b,c) \rangle}]$$
and because $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ we know
$$[L^{\langle (a,b,c) \rangle}:\mathbb{Q}]=2$$
Now I want to find an element which is invariant under $(a,b,c)$ which is not in $\mathbb{Q}$ which will then be the primitive element which characterises the fix field. Unfortunately all the canonical options
\begin{align*}
&a+b+c \\
&a b c \\
&ab + bc + ac  \\
& a^2b+b^2c + a^2c
\end{align*}
do not work since they are all in $\mathbb{Q}$. What is the element I am searching for?

The fixed field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$.
To verify that $\zeta_3$ lies in the fixed field, note that
$$\zeta_3 = \frac{\sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3}{\sqrt[3]{5}}.$$
So the image of $\zeta_3$ under the automorphism is equal to the image of $\sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3$ divided by the image of $\sqrt[3]{5}$. This is
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3^2}{\sqrt[3]{5}\zeta_3} = \zeta_3.$$
Thus, $\zeta_3$ is fixed. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, this is the fixed field.
